# HTTPGETCLOB gives error remote host did not respond

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to execute the below query from SQL (I Series)

SELECT systools.HTTPGETCLOB('http://www.ibm.com','')  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

But getting below error:

[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9FPJ.png)

Iseries version is V7R1.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me at 7.1

Your error message indicates that the remote site didn't respond...

Can you PING www.ibm.com from your i?

```
ping 'www.ibm.com'                                                     
Verifying connection to host system e2874.x.akamaiedge.net at address  
  23.64.119.102.                                                       
PING reply 1 from 23.64.119.102 took 20 ms. 256 bytes. TTL 55.         
PING reply 2 from 23.64.119.102 took 20 ms. 256 bytes. TTL 55.         
PING reply 3 from 23.64.119.102 took 20 ms. 256 bytes. TTL 55.         
PING reply 4 from 23.64.119.102 took 20 ms. 256 bytes. TTL 55.         
PING reply 5 from 23.64.119.102 took 20 ms. 256 bytes. TTL 55.         
Round-trip (in milliseconds) min/avg/max = 20/20/20.                   
Connection verification statistics: 5 of 5 successful (100 %).
```

It's possible your IBM i isn't configured properly or isn't allowed access to the internet.

Otherwise, are you up to date on PTF's?  Particularly the DB group PTF?

Comment: Hi Charles, I am not able to Ping from Iseries. I have to check the configuration to allow Iseries to access Internet.

Comment: `GO CFGTCP`, option 12 - Change TCP/IP domain information will allow you to see and modify the DNS servers your i uses.    Also check option 2 - Work with TCP/IP routes, to ensure that the *DFTROUTE is correct.   This all assumes you have the authority to do so.